# Why does a FormData object work but not a regular object in Jquery AJAX submit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am confused about using `data` objects in my AJAX submit.

Here's my submit AJAX script:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'/library/php/triggers.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:data,
  cache:false,
  dataType:'json',
  processData:false,
  contentType:false,
  success:function(result){console.log(result);}
});
```

This `data` works:

```
 var data=new FormData(this);
 data.append('hello','my friend');
```

But this `data` does not work:

```
var data={"hello":"my friend"};
```

Aren't these both JSON objects? What's the difference between these?

I also tried changing `contentType:false` to `contentType:'application/json'` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the difference between the two:
If you just did

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('hello', 'my friend');

console.log(data)
var data2 = {
  "hello": "my friend"
};
```

And then check your dev tools you would notice that:

```
    FormData {  }  ​
    <prototype>: FormDataPrototype { append: append(), delete: delete(), get: get(), … }
    append: function append()
    constructor: function ()
    delete: function delete()
    entries: function entries()
    forEach: function forEach()
    get: function get()
    getAll: function getAll()
    has: function has()
    keys: function keys()
    set: function set()
    values: function values()
    Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "FormData"
    Symbol(Symbol.iterator): 
function entries()`<prototype>: Object { … }
```

`Form.data()` has a lot of other properties in constructor [associated with methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#methods) that you can use on it, so browser treats it differently.
Last function : `function entries() <prototype>: Object { … }` is the same as regular object where data is being stored with getters and setters:

```
Object { hello: "my friend" }
​
hello: "my friend"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__()
__proto__: 
constructor: function Object()
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()
toString: function toString()
valueOf: function valueOf()
<get __proto__()>: function __proto__()
<set __proto__()>: function __proto__()
```

Also take notice that you last creation of object converted your string `'hello'` into key `hello:` while form data converts all keys and values into string.

So, in short this two are not the same objects.

Answer (score 1):

The `processing:false` is because browsers internally process FormData object the same way they do when submitting a `<form>`.

You want jQuery to process the plain object. It uses `$.param()` internally to create a form encoded string

```
var data = {"hello":"my friend"};

$.ajax({
  url:'/library/php/triggers.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:data,  
  dataType:'json',// what you expect to recieve  
  success:function(result){console.log(result);}
});
```

To recieve in php:

```
$hello = $_POST['hello'];
```

What jQuery does internally with the object:

```js
var data = {"hello":"my friend", foo:"bar"};

var processed = $.param(data);

console.log(processed)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: $.param doesn't work for me when I have contentType:false, but if I remove contentType:false, FormData doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need to use $.param yourself or even know it is there. I only showed it for explanation of what is done internally. As for the FormData the browser sets the content type header